# How to I redirect read requests to replica in Postgres Cluster?

Tags: postgresql, cluster

I have a Postgres Cluster of 2 servers currently. 
They are managed by Patroni with ETCD as my DCS.
I want to be able to redirect Read requests to the replica and Write requests to the master. I read that PGPOOL II could do this, but this looks to do the same job as Patroni so wondering if there are any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I've Used PGPool II to do this and it worked quite well. You have to have some kind of middleware that is able to look at the SQL and determine if it's a read request and then do the routing. That's where Patroni and PGPool are different.

The only other option I'm aware of is to make changes to your application so that you have separate DBs for writes and reads. Then you can configure your writes to go to your master and reads to go to your slave.

As a side note, it appears that Patroni really wants to have three servers because it uses RAFT and you have to have an odd number of servers to reliably avoid split-brain problems. If you've only got two servers, PGPool may be a better choice anyway.

Comment: thanks qhartman. I'm looking to add further servers down the line. ETCD solves that problem as I have more than 3 nodes in that cluster. I was looking at this as well, https://github.com/CrunchyData/crunchy-proxy which good do the same thing as pgpool ii. I'll take a look at both and see which works best for my situation.